# Data Sync Architecture between Mobile And ODATA API

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile

I'm having sync problems on my mobile application. The app works on-line and off-line. 
The main issues consists on sync time, data crush and sync interrupts.
I have an REST API that serves data and business logic to mobile device. The Rest API has also the authentication mechanism of the app.
To sync, the mobile app has an background job (battery consumption problem) that runs every 30 seconds. This process the data stored on local database (SQLLite) and makes some rest calls for each operation. Some operations requires to write on different entities which it could originate several calls for each operation since the rest api it is entity oriented based on ODATA protocol.

[image: Current Architecture]

At the moment, I'm studying new approaches to solve some of this problems.

I think, I want to entry on real-time database on the current the architecture...

I have some scenarios in mind, but my lack of knowledge on this kind of architectures makes me had some doubts about the best scenario.
My doubts are:

- If I add an real-time database (like firebase, realm or others...),
  should I keep the SQLLite database on the mobile app?
- Since I already have an rest api to manage the data how this should communicate with the real-time db? should be my current rest
  api "ask" to the real-time db the updates?
- It is possible to implement an action on the real-time db (firebase or others) that notifies my current API?
- Should the web evolve to use the real-time db also?

[image]

For what I found on the web, exists a lot of scenarios that can be followed depending on each case. However I don't find any clear scenario for my case. 
In abstract, my app needs to work on-line and off-line and syncs fully with an server api.

The current implemented sync mechanism on the mobile app it may be not the best. Some operations has to make some calls to api and wait for the answer to process the next calls. Exists some business logic to process these calls. On server side some requests can be a little slow depending on the volume of the data to process. 
Initial, my point is to improve the performance of the app with no sync issues.

Comment: Not enough information. Is your slowdown from the server taking a lot of time to derive its responses? Are responses consistent enough to make caching practical? Is your network dropping packets? Without knowing what is slowing things down, it's not possible to come up with an approach to speed them back up.

Comment: @JohnDoe I added some more information to the topic. Thank you.